# Avoiding fragmentation when saving files to BlackBerry filesystem. Best practice?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, filesystems, directory

In my application I need to save some file (a pdf) to the filesystem. My current method involves creating a directory for storing the files:

```
FileConnection fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pdfs/");
    if (!fc.exists())
        fc.mkdir();
    fc.close();
```

I then write to the directory with my file:

```
 fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/pdfs/" + filename, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!fc.exists())
        fc.create();
    OutputStream outStream = fc.openOutputStream();
    outStream.write(pdf);
    outStream.close();
    fc.close();
```

This all works fine, and my pdf arrives in my created directory. **My question is: will I run into trouble with the fact that I have hard coded a file path as my save destination.** With the BlackBerry API is it possible to retrieve a writeable folder which exists on all models/configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the system for the available roots using `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots()`. Note that it is not guaranteed that there will be an sdcard, or that it will be visible even if there is one (when in mass storage mode, for instance). I think that the only root guaranteed to be on all devices is internal storage (`"file:///Store"`).

There's (a little) more information [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Storing_files_in_the_file_system_1219757_11.jsp).

Comment: I also don't think that the "BlackBerry" folder exists on all. Sometimes it'll give you an error and expect "blackberry" instead.